# Openpyxl not writing to my Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write to an Excel worksheet but the code does not do anything. I have the file name right and it correctly detects the only sheet ('Sheet1') but when I try to write to a cell nothing happens. I am running Microsoft Office 365 if that matters.

I have tried

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Spendings 2019.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws['B3'] = 4
```

This does not change the Excel file at all when run.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the docs? You need

print(cell.value)

As explained https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Also, if you are making changes to the spreadsheet, you need to save it

Comment: I saved it but now I am getting error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Spendings 2019.xlsx'

Comment: Then I guess the file is already open by another program, or Python doesn't have write access to that folder...